# Flutter change the tab width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have tabs with 4 items and the last one is a tab with an icon. I want to change the width of the last tab, make it smaller. So, it'd look better. Using `Container` and giving a width didn't work. Any suggestions that make it work?

[image]

```dart
TabBar(
  controller: _controller,
  labelColor: Color(0xff666666),
  indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
  unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff666666),
  tabs: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onItemTapped(5);
      },
      child: Tab(
        text: 'Explore',
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/bookService');
      },
      child: Tab(
        text: 'Book Service',
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Shop',
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(
        FontAwesomeIcons.inbox,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change icon's size using `Transform` widget and using it's `scale` property and by wrapping `Icon` widget with it. Working code below:

```
Tab(
      icon: Transform.scale(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.ac_unit,
      ),
        scale: 0.6
      )
    ),
```

Also `Transform` widget doesn't affect the tabbar layout but only scales it's child. You may use the `scale` value per your need.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.